# WPF Desktop app - Failing to disable Maximize even when ResizeMode is CanMinimize

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

C# WPF Desktop app - Failing to disable Maximize even when ResizeMode is CanMinimize in custom window control. Image is of desired result:

[image: Disable Maximize desired]

Tried setting ResizeMode="CanMinimize" in XAML in upper declaration of the control. Tried even putting in constructor of control:

```
        public MaterialWindow()
        {
            WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, new WindowChrome()
            {
                CaptionHeight = 32,
                NonClientFrameEdges = NonClientFrameEdges.None,
                ResizeBorderThickness = new Thickness(4),
                UseAeroCaptionButtons = true
            });
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanMinimize; //  <= 

            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand, CloseWindow_Exec, CloseWindow_CanExec));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand, MinimizeWindow_Exec, MinimizeWindow_CanExec));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand, MaximizeWindow_Exec, MaximizeWindow_CanExec));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand, RestoreWindow_Exec, RestoreWindow_CanExec));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenuCommand, ShowSystemMenu_Exec, ShowSystemMenu_CanExec));
        }
```

Even tried calling a method that set ResizeMode after custom window constructed:

```
ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanMinimize; // window can only be minimized and restored
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by clearing the command binding to maximize.  Apparently it will not honor the ResizeMode.CanMinimize if the bindings are in place:

```
        public void DisableMaximize()
        {
            // clear the command bindings and set all EXCEPT MAXIMIZE command
            CommandBindings.Clear();
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand, CloseWindow_Exec, CloseWindow_CanExec));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand, MinimizeWindow_Exec, MinimizeWindow_CanExec));
            //CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand, MaximizeWindow_Exec, MaximizeWindow_CanExec));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand, RestoreWindow_Exec, RestoreWindow_CanExec));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenuCommand, ShowSystemMenu_Exec, ShowSystemMenu_CanExec));

            this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanMinimize; // window can only be minimized and restored
        }
```